# Is there a more readable way to write for k, v in pairs(my_table) do ... end in lua if I never use k?

Tags: coding-style, lua

Is there a more readable way in lua to write:

```
for k, v in pairs(my_table) do
    myfunction( v )
end
```

I'm never using k, so I'd like to take it out of the loop control, so it's clear I'm just iterating over the values. Is there a function like pairs() that only gives me a list of the values?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no standard function that only iterates values, but you *can* write it yourself if you wish. Here is such an iterator :

```
function values(t)
  local k, v
  return function()
    k, v = next(t, k)
    return v
  end
end
```

But normally people just use `pairs` and discard the first variable. It is customary in this case to name the unused variable `_` (an underscore) to clearly indicate the intent.

Answer (score 5):

I've seen people use the `_` variable instead of k or i.

Answer (score 1):

why would you use the pairs() function if you don't want the key/value pairs of the table you're enumerating then?

for example, this is even shorter to type:

```
local t = {"asdf", "sdfg", "dfgh"}

for i=1, #t do
    print(t[i])
end
```

otherwise, i always just did this:

```
local t = {"asdf", "sdfg", "dfgh"}

for _,v in pairs(t) do
    print(v)
end
```

edit: for your scenario, where you want to enumerate only values in a table with non-numeric keys, probably the clearest thing you could do would be to write your own table iterator function like this:

```
local t = {["asdf"] = 1, ["sdfg"] = 2, ["dfgh"] = 3}

function values(tbl)
    local key = nil
    return function()
            key = next(tbl, key)
            return tbl[key]
           end
end


for value in values(t) do
    print(value)
end
```

then, it is very explicit that you're only traversing the values of the table t. like pairs(), this is not guaranteed to traverse in order since it uses next().

Comment: I'm using the table as a map, so the keys are non-integers, so #t always returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

It's your coding style, really. If you can read it and you're consistent with it then it shouldn't matter.

However, I tend to use:
`for i,c in`
"i" standing for "index" and "c" standing for "child", but "v" for "value" works as well. And even if you're not using the index variable, it's still good practice.

Another thing you might do is:
`for n = 1, 10`
when dealing with numbers. But once again, it's you're coding style and as long as it's consistent you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

From [Lua Style Guide](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaStyleGuide):

```
The variable consisting of only an underscore "_" is commonly used as a placeholder when you want to ignore the variable:

for _,v in ipairs(t) do print(v) end
Note: This resembles the use of "_" in Haskell, Erlang, Ocaml, and Prolog languages, where "_" takes the special meaning of anonymous (ignored) variables in pattern matches. In Lua, "_" is only a convention with no inherent special meaning though. Semantic editors that normally flag unused variables may avoid doing so for variables named "_" (e.g. LuaInspect is such a case).
```

So I would expect underscore (`_`) name is more readable for unused variables.